# Website form data into Oracle fusion CRM

Tags: php, oracle

What is the best/simplest way to send data from a public website form into Oracle Fusion CRM? (The website is in PHP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is overly broad, so this would apply to the answer as well: Oracle Fusion has an [excellent API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e14294.pdf) you can use for communication. It all depends on what you're trying to send and what you wanna receive though.

Comment: Customer registration data - name, address, company etc. (For when, for instance, they request a sales person to call them.)

Comment: Then the API is what you're looking for, see the link.

Comment: So basically there would need to be a SOAP interface between the web form on the public website and the Oracle Fusion CRM?

Comment: @Sherlock and if you'd like to execute a custom Query with Joins and more complex selections what choices do you have? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Oracle Fusion Enterprise Repository:
**https://fusionappsoer.oracle.com/oer/index.jsp**

Here you can view all web services supported by Fusion CRM. What type of data those accept and what those return.